# Laravel Cashier 10 not installing via composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-cashier

I am setting up a subscription module and decided to use laravel cashier.But it isn't installing properly. What could I do doing wrong?

Here's the error.

```
 Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/contracts v1.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/contracts v1.0.2
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.3.0-BETA1 requires symfony/contracts ^1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[1.1.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3, v1.1.4, v1.1.5].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.3.0-BETA2 requires symfony/contracts ^1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[1.1.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3, v1.1.4, v1.1.5].
    - symfony/event-dispatcher v4.3.0-BETA1 requires symfony/contracts ^1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[1.1.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3, v1.1.4, v1.1.5].
    - symfony/event-dispatcher v4.3.0-BETA2 requires symfony/contracts ^1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[1.1.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3, v1.1.4, v1.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/contracts[1.1.x-dev, v1.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/contracts[v1.1.0, v1.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/contracts[v1.1.1, v1.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/contracts[v1.1.2, v1.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/contracts[v1.1.3, v1.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/contracts[v1.1.4, v1.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/contracts[v1.1.5, v1.0.2].
    - Installation request for symfony/contracts (locked at v1.0.2) -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[v1.0.2].
    - Installation request for laravel/cashier ^10.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/cashier[v10.1.0].
```

Comment: @msg How did you place the code in that container. I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Select the text and press the brackets in the toolbar (`{}`) for a preformatted block. Check the [editor help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Run `composer require 'symfony/contracts:^1.1'` and afterwards try to `require` the cashier package again.

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich, Thanks.

Comment: @msg thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes here from google. I tried @Nicolai suggestion and the error changed so ran

> compose update

and it worked perfectly.